# I have weekly averages, and weekly 2-minute peaks, can I estimate 30-second peaks?

Tags: time-series, predictive-models, normality-assumption, quantiles, types-of-averages

I have been given weekly averages and weekly 2-minute peaks of flow to a process. I'd like to predict the 30-second peak.

To clarify: By “weekly averages”, I mean that once a week, I get the average value of the process over the past week. By “2-minute peaks”, I mean that every week, I am given the highest 2-minute average value of the process of all continuous 2-minute intervals in the past week.

I'm pretty sure my current approach is full of issues, and I'll include it here for the sake of exciting some indignation at the abuse of these statistical concepts. Basically, I assume that all flows can be approximated by a normal distribution. Then I assume the 2-minute peak is approximately equal to the true 99.980th percentile of all flow rates (2 minutes divided by a week of minutes is 0.99980). Then I assume the 30-second peak is approximately equal to the true 99.995th percentile of all flow rates (30 seconds divided by a week of seconds is 0.99995). The graphics below demonstrate this approach.

[image: Example Observations Boxplots] [image: Example Approximation as Normal Distribution]

Note that in these charts I am using the *minimum* observed week average and the maximum observed 2-minute peak to approximate the normal distribution. That is because overestimating the 30-second peak is appropriate for my situation.

Is there a better way to estimate the 30-second peak? What are the major flaws with my current approach?

Here is the Python code I used to generate those plots, in case it is helpful:

```py
# imports
import pandas as pd
import scipy.stats as st
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# example data
df = pd.DataFrame( 
    columns = [
        'week average',
        'week 2-minute peak'
        ],
    data = np.array(
        [np.random.normal(loc=0.00, scale=0.33, size=60),
         np.random.normal(loc=1.16, scale=0.36, size=60)]
        ).T
    )

# boxplot of data
plt.title('Example Observations')
plt.ylabel('flow')
plt.boxplot([df['week average'], 
             df['week 2-minute peak']], 
            labels=['obseved week averages',
                    'observed week 2-minute peaks'])
plt.show()

# approximating z-value of known 2-minute peak and unknown 30-second peak
seconds_per_week = 60*60*24*7
z120 = st.norm.ppf(1-120/seconds_per_week)
z030 = st.norm.ppf(1-30/seconds_per_week)

# approximating true mean with the minimum of observed weekly averages
mean = min(df['week average']) # minimum

# aproximating true 2-minute peak with the maximum observed weekly 2-minute peak
peak120 = max(df['week 2-minute peak']) # maximum observed weekly peak

# relating z score to flow
def z_to_flow(z):
    return ((peak120-mean)/z120*z+mean)

def flow_to_z(flow):
    return flow-mean*z120/(peak120-mean)

# approximating 30-second peak
peak030 = z_to_flow(z030)

# plotting normal probability density function
x = np.linspace(st.norm.ppf(0.00001), st.norm.ppf(0.99999), 100)
y = st.norm.pdf(x)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(constrained_layout=True)
ax.plot(x, y)
ax.set_xlabel('z score')
ax.set_ylabel('rough probability of occurance')

# plotting points of interest
ax.plot([0,0],
        [min(y),max(y)*1.05 ],
        label = r'observed weekly average $\approx$ true mean')
ax.plot([z120,z120],
        [min(y),max(y)*1.05 ],
        label = r'observed 2-min peak $\approx$ 99.980th percentile')
ax.plot([z030,z030],
        [min(y),max(y)*1.05 ],
        label = r'99.995th percentile $\approx$ 30-s peak')
secax = ax.secondary_xaxis('top', functions=(z_to_flow, flow_to_z))
secax.set_xticks([mean,peak120,peak030])
secax.tick_params(labelrotation = 90)
secax.set_xlabel('flow')
ax.set_title('Example Flows Approximated as Normal Distribution\n')
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Excellent questions @Matt F. I will update the question to clarify.

Comment: Edits complete. Now see the second paragraph for clarification.

Comment: Thanks, that helps…but now I have more questions. 1) Do the weekly reports also give the (unaveraged) flow at the time of the report? I would expect so, and it might simplify the analysis. 2) Are the flows really from a normal distribution, in which tomorrow has the same normal distribution as two days from now? Perhaps the flow is better modeled as a Brownian motion, where the increments are normal, high flow tomorrow suggests high flow two days from now, and two days from now has a wider distribution than tomorrow’s. That model might seem more natural to me, depending on what is flowing.

Comment: @MattF., 1) The weekly reports do not also give the unaveraged flow at the time of the report. The problem statement in the question specifies all the information available. 2) Since I don't have the actual data, only the averages and the peaks, I'm not sure the flow rates are normally distributed. Unfortunately, I'm not sure what potential statistical models could be utilized here. Brownian motion? Maybe. This is a factory setting, not an observation of physical phenomena, so I'm not sure Brownian motion is an appropriate model here. I'm open to being convinced though.